# Trying to ensure that correct window is active right now

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to assert that the currently needed browser window is opened via selenium. 
My approach is to compare titles of the windows to each other, and if title doesn't match - switch to the next window and repeat procedure. But right now check of the last window (which is correct) doesn't happen.

*Method for collecting all opened browser windows:*

```
def collect_windows(self):
    windows = []
    try:
        for handle in self.driver.window_handles:
            windows.append(handle)
        return windows
    except:
        self.log.error(format_exc())
```

*Method that runs through the list and checks titles of the windows:*

```
def switch_window(self, window_title=''):
    windows_list = self.collect_windows()
    try:
        for window in windows_list:
            title = self.driver.title
            if window_title not in title:
                self.driver.switch_to.window(window)
        self.log.info(f"Switched to window: {window_title}")
    except:
        self.log.error(format_exc())
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing titles compare the window handles

```
def get_current_window_handle(self):
    return self.driver.current_window_handle

def switch_window(self, current_handle):
    for handle in self.driver.window_handles:
        if handle != current_handle:
            self.driver.switch_to.window(handle)
            self.log.info(f"Switched to window: {self.driver.title}")
            return


current_window_handle = get_current_window_handle()
# open new window
switch_window(current_window_handle)
```